# CERTIFICATE OF APPRECIATION

Tags: grammar, word-choice

This certificate is presented to XYZ (employee name)*in recognition of his contributions to bringing strategic changes in ABC's (company name) procurement process and e-Tendering*

Is this grammatically correct? should i use preposition "to" again after AND (....e-Tendering)? there are two achievement, one is bringing strategic changes and another one is contribution in e-Tendering.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may indeed find it more readable with a preposition:

> This certificate is presented to  in recognition of his contributions to e-Tendering, and to strategic changes in 's procurement process.

Comment: The comma there is incorrect, but the wording makes much more sense.